# El servicio de docker depends_on no funciona al reiniciar el servidor

Tags: linux, docker, debian, docker-compose

Tengo el siguiente archivo docker-compose.yml:

```
services:
  db:
    image: **
    ports:
      - **
    restart: always
    environment:
      MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD: **
      MARIADB_USER: **
      MARIADB_PASSWORD: **
      MARIADB_DATABASE: **

  nginx:
    depends_on:
      - backend
      - frontend
    restart: always
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: ./Nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"

  backend:
    image: ***
    depends_on:
      - db
    restart: always
    build: ./
    ports:
      - **

  frontend:
    image: ***
    depends_on:
      - backend
    restart: always
```

Al hacer el docker-compose up funciona perfectamente, el problema es que al reiniciarse el servidor, todos los servicios arrancan al mismo tiempo, por lo que no hace efecto el depend_on, y no conecta correctamente con la bbdd. Para corregirlo tengo que entrar y manualmente hacer el docker-compose stop, y luego el docker-compose up y ya vuelve a funcionar, pero necesito automatizar esto.
Agradezco cualquier ayuda

Comment: Y si usas la sintaxis "larga" pa decirle cuál es la condición para determinar que el servicio dependiente ya está listo? https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#depends_on

Comment: no, me da error de sintaxis a pesar de estar igual que en el ejemplo de la documentacion

Comment: Qué versión de docker tienes?

Comment: la 3, probé a bajar a la 2 porque leí que la 3 no aceptaba la versión larga, y ahí me lo acepto pero me da un nuevo error: ERROR: for backend Service "db" is missing a healthcheck configuration

Comment: Posiblemente sea eso. Necesitas especificar el criterio para que docker sepa que el servicio está arriba, el healthcheck

Comment: y este criterio como sería? es para que backend espere hasta que db este correctamente levantado